# Modelling Air Resistance in Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

[free fall ODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zR4M.jpg)

I want to determine when is this model physically realistic.

I found the stability of the critical points through setting the derivative to 0.

The critical points are v = +/- sqrt(g*m/k).

I have determined the  negative point to be unstable  since if I plugged in a very negative number into the given equation the derivative would be negative but if I plugged in 0 ( or another number in between - sqrt(g*m/k) and + sqrt(g*m/k)) it would be positive. I applied the same theory to determine  sqrt(g*m/k) is stable.

I also know that when v = sqrt(m*g/k) , terminal velocity is reached. Therefore this model is accurate before terminal velocity. Is my logic here physically sound or is there something I need to consider additionally.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

This model is an essential part of classical physics. There's no need to determine whether it is physically realistic. It is realistic in the simple setting of the problem; however, it is not realistic in reality. For instance, the problem assumes the object is a point so you don't have to account for non-uniform shape that interacts with the air differently.

What you did is more in line with stability analysis.